# performance issues with jquery textbox changed ajax postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'd like to update SQL when a textbox is changed by the user, but what I'm worried about is updating it every character press essentially will be sending a SQL UPDATE command every single time, potentially even simultaneously if the user is typing fast.

what's sort of a best practice approach for making it so that i only post the updated textbox after, say maybe, 2 seconds of the user no longer updating the textbox?

probably some variation of binding to the keyup event of the textbox and using a settimeout and cleartimeout to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use TextBox leave events. after you done with things. [Textbox Leave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_methods.aspx)

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  string StrSql = Textbox1.Text; // your sql queries goes here
  using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constr))
  {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, con); 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the google docs approach and restart a counter everytime there is a change in the textbox.  If there is no change for 5 seconds, then update/save

Answer (score 0):

Does it absolutely have to be bound to a keyup event?

You could also do a on -> focus, then set maybe a 2 second interval SQL update, then on blur /  the function will desist.

That way you're not pounding your server with requests on every key event.

Comment: THen I suggest doing a focus event that sets a interval, after 2-3 seconds pend it to the DB.